# Jdbctemplate utilities for insert statement

Tags: spring, jdbctemplate

Is there any existing utility to do in a better/faster way a DB insert?
Now this is what I'm using (the are a lot of fields, I truncated the field list):

```
public void insert(Ing ing){

        String[] fields=new String[]{"field1","field2","field3"};
        Object[] params=new Object[]{ing.getField1(),ing.getField2(),ing.getField3()};

        String[] paramsPH=new String[fields.length];
        for(int i=0;i<paramsPH.length;i++) paramsPH[i]="?";

        String sql= "INSERT INTO ing("+StringUtils.join(fields,",")+") VALUES ("+StringUtils.join(paramsPH,",")+");";

        getJdbcTemplate().update(sql,params);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my Spring JdbcTemplate projects, I ususally create a generic `BaseDao<T>` class that has a method `saveObject(T obj)`.
to achieve this, I use `SimpleJdbcInsert` like this:

```
//Constants, from BaseDAO interface that this method implements
String TABLE_NAME = "tableName";
String GENERATED_KEY = "generatedKey";

/**
 * Save an object using a {@link BaseObjectMapper} returned from the method {@link #getObjectMapper()}
 * Returns the generated key if the map generated by the {@link BaseObjectMapper} contains an entry for {@value #GENERATED_KEY}
 * @param the object to be saved
 */
@Override
public int saveObject(T obj){
    MapSqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource();
    //the mapper must transform an object to a map
    //and add the table name where to insert, and if any, a generated key
    Map<String, Object> paramsMap = getObjectMapper().mapObject(obj);
    String table = (String) paramsMap.remove(TABLE_NAME);
    if(table == null){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The ObjectMapper of "+obj.getClass()+" must return the table name among the result map of mapObject method");
    }

    String generatedKey = (String) paramsMap.remove(GENERATED_KEY);

    String[] colNames = paramsMap.keySet().toArray(new String[paramsMap.keySet().size()]);

    for(String col: colNames){
        params.addValue(col, paramsMap.get(col));
    }
    //You can have it as a class attribute and create it once the DAO is being instantiated
    SimpleJdbcInsert genericJdbcInsert = new SimpleJdbcInsert(jdbcInsert.getJdbcTemplate().getDataSource())
                                        .withSchemaName(currentSchema).withTableName(table)
                                        .usingColumns(colNames);

    if(generatedKey != null){
        genericJdbcInsert = genericJdbcInsert.usingGeneratedKeyColumns(generatedKey);
        return genericJdbcInsert.executeAndReturnKey(paramsMap).intValue();
    }else{
        genericJdbcInsert.execute(params);
    }
    return 0;
}


protected BaseObjectMapper<T> getObjectMapper(){
//Implement it in your concrete DAO classes
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("You must implemnt this method in your concrete DAO implementation");
}
```

Here is the `BaseObjectMapper` interface:

```
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;

import com.atlasaas.ws.dao.BaseDao;
import com.atlasaas.ws.entities.BaseEntity;

public interface BaseObjectMapper<T extends BaseEntity> extends RowMapper<T>{

/**
 * Method to transform an object into a {@link Map}
 * The result map must contain all columns to be inserted as keys
 * It also must contain the Table name corresponding to the given object
 * The table name must be associated to the key of value: {@link BaseDao#TABLE_NAME}
 * Optionally, if you want your save methods to return a generated primary key value
 * you should include an entry referencing the the generated column name. This entry
 * must then be associated to the key of value: {@link BaseDao#GENERATED_KEY}
 * @param obj The object to be transformed
 * @return the result of this object transformation
 */
    Map<String, Object> mapObject(T obj);
}
```

If you really want to use SQL in your code, you can use:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcOperations#(String sql, SqlParameterSource paramSource)
```

where your SQL string would be something like this:
    insert into SOME_TABLE(COL1,COL2,COL3) values (:col1Val,:col2Val,:col3Val)
and your `SqlParameterSource` is built this way:

```
MapSqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource();
params.addValue("col1Val", val1);
params.addValue("col2Val", val2);
params.addValue("col3Val", val3);
```

I hope this helps

Comment: getObjectMapper().mapObject seems what I need, I will try it. Thank you

Comment: You are welcome, and please see my edit, for additional alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Check this :

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

JdbcTemplate jt = new JdbcTemplate...// some instance... ;
String tableName="nameDateTable";//your happy table

LinkedHashMap<String,Object>map= new LinkedHashMap<String,Object>();
map.put("col1Name","blabla"); //column name and value 
map.put("dateAdd",new Date());//column name and value 
// etc..

//  You can place any map here (LinkedHashMap!). Here is a magical query:

String sql = "INSERT INTO "+tableName+" (\""+StringUtils.join(map.keySet(), "\",\"")+"\") VALUES ("+StringUtils.repeat("?", ",", map.size())+");";
jt.update(sql, map.values().toArray());
```

The most important in this solution is

```
 String sql = "INSERT INTO "+tableName+" 
(\""+StringUtils.join(map.keySet(), "\",\"")+"\") VALUES ("+StringUtils.repeat("?", ",", map.size())+");";
jt.update(sql, map.values().toArray());
```

and **LinkedHashMap**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use parameterized SQL to make it a bit simpler

Your code would look something like this

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO ing(field1, field2, field3) values(?, ?, ?)"; 
Object[] params=new Object[]{ing.getField1(),ing.getField2(),ing.getField3()};
getJdbcTemplate().update(sql,params);
```

Comment: Sorry, i did not understand... I have to manage a large number of fields, so I don't like to repeat many times "?,?,?,?,?,?"... count it to match the fields and so on, then I build up an array join to write this string automatically, but maybe there were a smart way to do it.

Comment: @Tobia: using named parameters would be an improvement over this, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/16362128/217324

Comment: I'm already using namedprov for "select" queries, I will try also for inserts