# Is there any way of getting resultset after preparedstatement closed ? ( java )

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement, resultset

I made a static method for executing the queries like this below

(this is in ServerProcess class)

```
public static ResultSet insertRow(Connection conn, String query){
    PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
    ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
    pstmt.close();
    return rs;
}
```

and trying to get & use the resultset from here

```
ResultSet rs = ServerProcess.insertRow(conn, query)
    while(rs.next()){
    String nameOfEachOne = rs.getString("MEMBER_NAME");
    System.out.println(nameOfEachOne);  
}
```

But, as far as I know, once statement(or preparedstatement) closed, resultset would be bound to get closed as a knock-on consequences.

I would like to use it in this way somehow, but I can't figure out how to do it. Is there any possible ways to get information set after the statement closed ?

Comment: _Is there any way of getting resultset after preparedstatement closed ? ( java )_ No

Comment: suppose this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25493837/java-cant-use-resultset-after-connection-close) discuss more about your issue and a solution for it.

Comment: Yes, I know it sounds like non-sense, but I'm just curious and wonder if there's some good idea.

Comment: Provide a callback - or use Spring's JdbcTemplate

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't receive the ResultSet or read anything from it when the parent PreparedStatement is already closed.

What you can do is to work with a Consumer which reads the ResultSet before you close the PreparedStatement and then returns any Business-Object you need:

The Consumer-Interface:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface SQLConsumer<T extends ResultSet, E>// where E is going to be your Business-Object Type
{
    E accept(T resultSet) throws IOException;
}
```

The Method now returns what the parser returns, but closes everything properly:

```
public static <E> E insertRow(Connection conn, String query, SQLConsumer<? super ResultSet, ? extends E> parser)
{
    E result;

    // use the try-with-resources functionality
    try (PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query)
    ; ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery())
    {
        // give the ResultSet to the parser to process it before closing the PreparedStatement
        result = parser.accept(rs);
    }

    return result;
}
```

And parsing the result:

```
public void callingMethod()
{
    ArrayList<String> result = insertRow(conn, "MY_QUERY", this::parseResultSet);
}

private ArrayList<String> parseResultSet(ResultSet resultSet) throws IOException
{
    ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
    while (resultSet.next())
    {
        values.add(resultSet.getString("MEMBER_NAME"));
    }

    return values;
}
```

Comment: careful, many ResultSet operations throw SQLException, which a `Consumer<T>` will not allow

Comment: Yes, just saw that in your answer :p

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer. It's the first time I saw the Consumer Interface. For using&referring your answer, I needed to study it ^^;

Comment: Extended my Example a little bit ;)

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you would never expose a ResultSet like that at all, it's a very mutable/stated object. However if you want to provide it, and still close it, you can use it via a lambda function:

```
@FunctionalInterface interface SQLConsumer<T> {
    public void accept(T t) throws SQLException; //default functional interfaces can't throw
}

public void query(String sql, SQLConsumer<? super ResultSet> action) {
    ResultSet rs = /* various jdbc code */;
    action.accept(rs);
    rs.close(); //and other resources
}

//In usage:
query("SELECT * FROM my_table", rs -> {
    String s = rs.getString(1); //example
});
```

Of course, you can make various methods like this, and [I've actually done abstraction](https://github.com/Codelanx/CodelanxCommons/blob/master/src/main/java/com/codelanx/commons/data/SQLDataType.java#L68-L102) like that myself for personal projects across different RDBMSes.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer. the term 'lambda' looks difficult and makes me remind physics and mathematics :) I'll try it on today !

Comment: here a lambda is essentially an "anonymous method" (like anonymous classes). It's similar to the mathematics definition only in that it represents a function (but not physics, since that's wavelength)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CachedRowSet`.

```java
RowSetFactory factory = RowSetProvider.newFactory();
CachedRowSet rowset = factory.createCachedRowSet();
rowset .setUsername(username);
rowset .setPassword(password);
rowset .setUrl("jdbc:mySubprotocol:mySubname"); // or setDataSource() 
rowset .setCommand("select * from table");
rowset.execute();  // now you have populate data
```

There are two advantages

1. Don't need prepareStatement
2. No problem to closing your connection or prepare statement comparing your method