# Simple select using SQLite java driver 3.21.0 does not return data

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I am facing a problem issuing a very simple select using SQLite and java on MacOS.

here is my code:

```
public class TestJDBC1 
{

public static Connection connect_DB() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        // db parameters
        String url = "jdbc:sqlite:/Users/Shared/DB_Farmaci/oracle-sample.db";
        // create a connection to the database
        conn = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(url);

        System.out.println("Connection a SQLite stabilita.");

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return conn;
}

public static void main( String[] args ) throws ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException, SQLException
{
    Connection conn = connect_DB();
    try 
    {
      conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TestJDBC1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    try 
    {
        Statement S = null ;
        ResultSet rs = null ;
        S = conn.createStatement();

        String queryS = "select deptno, dname, loc from dept ;" ;
        rs = S.executeQuery(queryS);

        S.close();
        conn.close();

        int x = 0;
        while (rs.next()) 
        {
          x++;
          System.out.println(rs.getInt("deptno") +  "\t" + 
                             rs.getString("dname") + "\t" +
                             rs.getDouble("loc"));
        }
        if (x > 0) 
        {
            System.out.println("# rows returned => " + x);
        } else 
        {
            System.out.println("no rows returned");
        }
    } catch (SQLException se) {
        System.out.println(se);
        System.out.println("errore DB");
    }
}
```

As you can see it is really simple but it does not return any data.

My Environment is the following:

1. NetBeans 8.2
2. sqlite-jdbc-3.21.0.jar (current version )

Using similar code I can create tables and insert rows into the DB, so setup of the environment should be ok ( Properties=> Libraries => both on compile and run).

I also tried on Eclipse, with the same, negative result. I also tried all backward JDBC driver versions I found, same situation. I am using DB Browser for SQLite 3.10.1, and I can read the data I am looking for.

I have SQLite installed on my Mac and I can read data using command line commands.

It looks like a driver malfunction, unless I am missing something very important.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot access your result set after closing connections. refer to [Java - Can't use ResultSet after connection close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25493837/java-cant-use-resultset-after-connection-close).

call your close() after you have finished using the resultSet.

```
    String queryS = "select deptno, dname, loc from dept ;" ;
    rs = S.executeQuery(queryS);

    //remove your close from here.

    int x = 0;
    while (rs.next()) 
    {
      x++;
      System.out.println(rs.getInt("deptno") +  "\t" + 
                         rs.getString("dname") + "\t" +
                         rs.getDouble("loc"));
    }
    if (x > 0) 
    {
        System.out.println("# rows returned => " + x);
    } else 
    {
        System.out.println("no rows returned");
    }


    //move your close here
    S.close();
    conn.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You close the connection and statement before processing the result set. That is not possible (and should have lead to an `SQLException` when you used `rs.next()`, which you didn't post).

You need to change your code to something like:

```
try (Connection conn = connect_DB()) {
    // other actions with connection

    String queryS = "select deptno, dname, loc from dept ;" ;
    try (Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
         ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(queryS)) {

        int x = 0;
        while (rs.next())  {
            x++;
            // etc
        }

    } catch (SQLException se) {
        se.printStackTrace()
        System.out.println("errore DB");
    }
}
```

I used [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) here, as it will simplify your code and prevent mistakes like this, because resources like the result set will be limited to the scope of their parent object. At the end of a try-with-resources, Java will automatically call the `close()` method.

I suggest you read a tutorial on JDBC and check its Javadoc to get more information on how to use the JDBC api.