# How do I disply the result of a function using a count query on my jsp page?

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

A table named `teacher` contains the `name`, `contact` and `email` 
CountTeacher function:

```
public ResultSet countTeacher() throws SQLException{
  try {
      con=Dbconnection.getCon();
      stmt=con.prepareStatement("select COUNT(*) from teacher");
      rs=stmt.executeQuery();
  }catch(Exception e) {
      e.getMessage();
      con.close();
  }
  return rs;
}
```

how do i call this funnction and display it on my jsp page using scriplets
I imported the java file with this function on the page I want to display the result on and gave it an id. How do I call it now

Comment: you imported what exactly? Why not just use a servlet for this? Also we stopped using scriptlets since 2003.

Answer (score 0):

You returned `ResultSet` reference `rs` after closing the connection.

`ResultSet`uses cursor to point the rows returned by the database query. 
If you close connection before actually using the result, the `ResultSet` would be useless, as the connection is closed, it removes the cursor too.

It is worth [reading this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25493837/java-cant-use-resultset-after-connection-close)

As a suggestion to your problem, I would recommend below approach..

Make a POJO for your table..

```
class Teacher{
    private String name;
    private String contact;
    private String email;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getContact() {
        return contact;
    }

    public void setContact(String contact) {
        this.contact = contact;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

And, now in your method, you should return `list` of `teacher` which can be passed to some other method calls, even when the database connection is closed.

```
    public List<Teacher> countTeacher() throws SQLException {
        try {
            con = Dbconnection.getCon();
            stmt = con.prepareStatement("select COUNT(*) from teacher");
            rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            Teacher teacher = new Teacher();
            List<Teacher> teachers = new ArrayList<Teacher>();
            while(rs.next()){
                String name = rs.getString("name");
                String contact = rs.getString("contact");
                String email = rs.getString("email");

                teacher.setName(name);
                teacher.setContact(contact);
                teacher.setEmail(email);

                teachers.add(teacher);
            }
            return teachers;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
        finally{
            con.close();
        }
    }
```