# Make ResultSet as a result of a generic function QueryRunner in Java and JDBC

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, resultset

I have a function `QueryRunner` that takes a query, runs it and returns the result.

```java
public static ResultSet QueryGetter(String query) {
    Connection connection = null;
    ResultSet rslt = null;
    try {
        Class.forName(driverName);
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url + ":" + port + "/" + dbName, 
                                                 username, password);
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        rslt = statement.executeQuery(query);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(QueriesRunner.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
    return rslt;
```

However, when I use it to run a query, I get *"Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed"*. It is because I close the connection.

How can I modify the return signature of my function to make it work?

I tried using a `List`, but the thing is that I have to distinguish between `int` and `String` by using `rslt.getString()`.

I don't want to do that. I want to return the content of the ResultSet regardless of the type of the object in the SQL table (int, date, String ...). I will then process the content later, in another function.

Comment: returning `ResultSet` could lead to resource leaks, it is better to handle them in one place and close it.
You can create custom class similar ti the `ResultSet` results and assign it here

Comment: you can try `rslt.gotObject()`

Comment: but how can I return a class similar to the ResultSet without knowing the content of my sql Table ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java - Can't use ResultSet after connection close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25493837/java-cant-use-resultset-after-connection-close)

Answer (score 0):

**You can't access the `ResultSet` if you** already **closed the connection**.
So you need to pass your converter as parameter of the QueryGetter method.

You need to define a `Converter` interface (you can also define generics to have a better code)

```
public interface Converter {
    public Object from(ResultSet rs);
}
```

and change the `QueryGetter` method to get this `Converter` as a parameter and retrieving a `List` of objects instead of a `ResultSet`.
Something like:

```
  // Pass the converter as parameter
   // I also changed the name of the method in lowercase that is better practice
   public static List<Object> queryGetter(String query, Converter converter) {
        // Creates the list
        List list = new ArrayList(); 
        Connection connection = null;
        ResultSet rslt = null;
        try {
            Class.forName(driverName);
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url + ":" + port + "/" + dbName, 
                                                     username, password);
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            rslt = statement.executeQuery(query);
            // Loop through the result set
            while (rslt.next()) {
                // Convert the current record to an object
                Object record = convert.from(rslt);
                // Add it to the list
                list.add(record);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(QueriesRunner.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
        }
        return list;   // Return a list
    }
```

Note that this is a very similar approach that has been used by spring jdbc using `JdbcTemplate` and [`NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html#query-java.lang.String-org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper-) classes, for example in the method `query` where `Convert` is named `RowMapper` in spring jdbc, but does pratically the same.

> Query given SQL to create a prepared statement from SQL, mapping each row to a Java object via a RowMapper.

So my tip is: if this is not only for studying purpose **don't reinvent the wheel** and **use existing code**.