# Set parameter for identical subquery in PreparedStatement

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have PreparedStatement like this:

```
PreparedStatement st = conn
                    .prepareStatement("Select * from "
                            + "(select Count(*) from uch_otstyp b,prov_uch p "
                            + "where b.\"ID_Poezd\"=?"
                            + "and (b.\"NachKm\"*1000+b.\"NachM\")>? "
                            + "and (b.\"NachKm\"*1000+b.\"NachM\")<=? "
                            + "and b.\"ID_Poezd\"=p.\"ID_Poezd\" "
                            + "and b.\"ID_Uch\"=p.\"ID_Uch\" "
                            + "and p.\"MES\"=? "
                            + "and p.\"GOD\"=? "
                            + "and p.\"Nput\"=? "
                            + "and b.\"Kod_Otstup\"=? "
                            + "and b.\"DEPTH\"<1),"
                            + ""
                            + "(select Count(*) from uch_otstyp b,prov_uch p "
                            + "where b.\"ID_Poezd\"=?"
                            + "and (b.\"NachKm\"*1000+b.\"NachM\")>? "
                            + "and (b.\"NachKm\"*1000+b.\"NachM\")<=? "
                            + "and b.\"ID_Poezd\"=p.\"ID_Poezd\" "
                            + "and b.\"ID_Uch\"=p.\"ID_Uch\" "
                            + "and p.\"MES\"=? "
                            + "and p.\"GOD\"=? "
                            + "and p.\"Nput\"=? "
                            + "and b.\"Kod_Otstup\"=? "
                            + "and b.\"DEPTH\">=1)"
                            + "and b.\"DEPTH\"<2)");
```

Parameter values of each subquery are identic. How can I set parameters only for one subquery and automaticaly fill parameters of another(not for each subquery)?

Comment: Have you done any research / tried anything so far?

Comment: I tried loops and it works but I look for more efficient way

Comment: Thank you! I don't know SQL but now I can upvote with confidence and hope someone finds your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use named parameters, so that when a parameter appears multiple times in a query you would only have to specify it once. JDBC doesn't support named parameters, but you can write code to find the parameter names in a SQL string and figure out the order they appear so that the arguments can be added to the PreparedStatement. [Spring-Jdbc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html) does this for you with the NamedParameterJdbcTemplate, [here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16362128/217324). This is in core spring, the package that implements the parameter-munging is [`org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-jdbc/3.0.1.RELEASE/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/package-info.java).