# Unable to know whats going wrong with JdbcTemplateSupport

Tags: java, spring

I'm writing a program in spring to get the total number of records and to insert a record . my total number of records works fine, but my insert is giving me an exception.

Below is my code

```
@Component
public class DaoImpl extends JdbcDaoSupport {

    private DataSource dataSource;
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;
    private JdbcDaoSupport jdbcDaoSupport;


    // getCount of rows

    public int getNumberOfRecords() {
        String sql = "select count(*) from student";
        return this.getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(sql, Integer.class);
    }

    // insert using named parameters
    public void InsertUsingNamedParameters(StudentBean studentBean) {

        String paramSql = "insert into Student (id, name, age) values (:id, :name,:age)";
        HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("id", 10);
        params.put("name", "new userX");
        params.put("age", 35);
        this.getJdbcTemplate().update(paramSql, params);
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my main method.

```
package org.Main;

import org.Service.DaoImpl;
import org.model.StudentBean;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class MainStudent {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");

        DaoImpl dao = context.getBean("daoImpl", DaoImpl.class);
        dao.InsertUsingNamedParameters(new StudentBean());
        System.out.println(dao.getNumberOfRecords());
      }
    }
}
```

Here is my **Spring.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"

    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="org.model, org.Service"></context:component-scan>
    <context:annotation-config />
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"></property>
        <property name="url"
            value="My jdbc url"></property>
        <property name="username" value="my user name"></property>
        <property name="password" value="my password"></property>

    </bean>
    <bean id="daoImpl" class="org.Service.DaoImpl">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

The best part is when I tried doing the same using `NamedParameterJdbctemplate`, this worked fine.

But in my xml I didn't have

```
<bean id="daoImpl" class="org.Service.DaoImpl">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    </bean>
```

Is this bean code causing that error?

This is pretty confusing. please let me know where am I going wrong and how can I fix this.

Below is my Exception

> Jul 20, 2016 4:04:07 PM
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext
>   prepareRefresh INFO: Refreshing
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@1c12fb0:
>   startup date [Wed Jul 20 16:04:07 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
>   Jul 20, 2016 4:04:07 PM
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader
>   loadBeanDefinitions INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path
>   resource [spring.xml] Jul 20, 2016 4:04:07 PM
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory
>   registerBeanDefinition INFO: Overriding bean definition for bean
>   'daoImpl' with a different definition: replacing [Generic bean: class
>   [org.Service.DaoImpl]; scope=singleton; abstract=false;
>   lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0;
>   autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null;
>   factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null;
>   defined in file
>   [C:\D\SpringMVC\SpringDataBases\bin\org\Service\DaoImpl.class]] with
>   [Generic bean: class [org.Service.DaoImpl]; scope=; abstract=false;
>   lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0;
>   autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null;
>   factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null;
>   defined in class path resource [spring.xml]] Jul 20, 2016 4:04:07 PM
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource
>   setDriverClassName INFO: Loaded JDBC driver:
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver Jul 20, 2016 4:04:08 PM
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader
>   loadBeanDefinitions INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path
>   resource [org/springframework/jdbc/support/sql-error-codes.xml] Jul
>   20, 2016 4:04:08 PM
>   org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory  INFO:
>   SQLErrorCodes loaded: [DB2, Derby, H2, HSQL, Informix, MS-SQL, MySQL,
>   Oracle, PostgreSQL, Sybase, Hana] Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException:
>   PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [insert into Student (id, name, age)
>   values (:id, :name,:age)]; The index 1 is out of range.; nested
>   exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The
>   index 1 is out of range.  at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:108)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:649)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:870)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:931)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:941)
>     at org.Service.DaoImpl.InsertUsingNamedParameters(DaoImpl.java:62)
>     at org.Main.MainStudent.main(MainStudent.java:14) Caused by:
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The index 1 is out of
>   range.    at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:171)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.setterGetParam(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:700)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.setObjectNoType(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:896)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.setObject(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:921)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:440)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValueInternal(StatementCreatorUtils.java:235)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:166)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.ArgumentPreparedStatementSetter.doSetValue(ArgumentPreparedStatementSetter.java:66)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.ArgumentPreparedStatementSetter.setValues(ArgumentPreparedStatementSetter.java:47)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:875)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:870)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:633)
>     ... 5 more

Comment: causing "what" error?

Comment: Hi @Stultuske, thanks for pointing that out. :) I forgot to add the Exception. I've updated my question. Thanks again:)

Comment: here seems to be your issue: he doesn't find the index
The index 1 is out of range.; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The index 1 is out of range. at

Comment: @Stultuske, no where I gave the index, When I tried with `NamedParameterJdbctemplate` and same didn't throw any Exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confused with `JdbcTemplate` and `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`, Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16359316/namedparameterjdbctemplate-vs-jdbctemplate)

Query `"insert into Student (id, name, age) values (:id, :name,:age)";` works fine with `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` since it has named parameters instead of `'?'` place holders.

change your query to `"insert into Student (id, name, age) values (?, ?, ?)";` and try to use `JdbcTemplate#update(String sql, Object... args) throws DataAccessException` method, it should work.

Just fyi, you are mixing xml bean configuration and component-scan, it's not recommended.